# How to Change iPhone between Silent and Vibrate

Tags: iphone, vibrate, sound-volume

I have an iPhone 5s and I only like to use silent and vibrate.  I never use the sound.  Is there a way that I can assign the switch on the side of the phone to be either silent or on vibrate?  I don't mind using the volume buttons on the side either, like i did when i had android, but i noticed that apple doesn't easily let you use move between vibrate and silent without going into the settings menu.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean 'silent and vibrate'?  Do you mean no noise and no vibration for 1) and then no noise but vibration for 2) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set the phone to not vibrate on ring, but vibrate on silent, then you could swap your ringtone for one that makes no sound.
You'd have to repeat that for each notification type below, if you wanted nothing at all to make a sound.

I made my own, but Google has a lot of results if you search for 'silent ringtone'

The side switch will then swap between silent [on] & vibrate [off]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

No, it isn't possible to change that in iOS. However, Apple's "silent" mode would be Do Not Disturb, which can be accessed in Control Center.

So as an alternative to the side switch, you can make sure that Control Center is enabled in the lock screen and then simply swipe up from the bottom and tap the moon icon. It isn't as convenient as the hardware switch, but certainly much better than opening Settings.

Also, some videos (in certain apps), for example, require that the switch on the side of the phone is On, so you might need to toggle it every now any then anyway.